# How can I respond to a key press, without a CRLF, in Raku?

Tags: raku, onkeypress

I would like to implement:

```
Press any key to continue...
```

That responds to, well, any key *without* pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

`Term::ReadKey` does not implement this behavior. It requires a CRLF.

I'm using [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2).

```
[19] > $*KERNEL
darwin
[20] > $*DISTRO
macos (13.0.1)
[21] > $*RAKU
Raku (6.d)
[22] > $*VM
moar (2022.12)
```

Comment: Raku has `prompt`, but I don't believe it suits your requirements.

Comment: Windows-only: `raku -MNativeCall -e"sub _getch(--> int32) is native(q|msvcrt|) {*}; print q|press any key to continue...| andthen _getch;"`

Comment: Aiui the terminal API (for any consumer, eg any programming language) only allows that sort of thing if you use "raw" or "rare" modes [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode), and, conversely, if you do that, you can do more or less anything you want to. If I'm right, then I presume the things to consider include relevant SO Qs (eg [\[raku\] ones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+terminal+raw)) and/or existing packages that support raw mode -- either [Raku ones?](https://raku.land/?q=terminal) or foreign ones (a plain C lib would likely be most appropriate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will have to use a module to be able to do that in Raku.  [Term::termios](https://raku.land/github:krunen/Term::termios) comes to mind.

Comment: There is also Terminal::Print and family. CAVEAT: Using raw input like this will put your terminal into raw mode, which means that...at minimum... you will need to use "\r\n" instead of just "\n" when outputting to the terminal.